# Can you always have your org included in apex hammer tests?

Tags: apex

Reading about the apex hammer tests in [this trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro), and it seems like SFDC runs the hammer against orgs selectively.

> Before each major service upgrade, Salesforce runs all Apex tests on your behalf through a process called Apex Hammer. The Hammer process runs in the current version and next release and compares the test results. This process ensures that the behavior in your custom code hasn’t been altered as a result of service upgrades. The Hammer process *picks orgs selectively and doesn’t run in all orgs*. Issues found are triaged based on certain criteria. Salesforce strives to fix all issues found before each new release. *(Emphasis Added)*

Suppose I have a client with a complex org. Can I opt in for my org to always be included in the hammer tests before the new releases?

Comment: Please include any links to articles you were "reading about" and also cite specific sections within your post.

Comment: I kind of guessed for you, since that's the only immediately accessible public page I could find. Feel free to *[edit]* if you have additional resources or want to modify your question further.

Comment: @sfdcfox - yep that's the page i was reading that made me ask the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the SF AE on the account, and was told not at this time.